# Detect end of speech Asterisk 13

Tags: speech-recognition, asterisk

We would like to use the asterisk13 (RECORD or Mixmonitor or any other) recording functions in which speech-end detection occurs after a certain quiet time. We took this .wav file and submitted the google recognition api via REST.
We tried in several ways to do this process of detection of end of speech and we did not have success.
Anyone have an idea how I can work around this problem?

thank you very much.
Jeferson Oliveira.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Record() function for this.

Record(myrecording.wav,5)

This will record a file named myrecording.wav and will wait for 5 seconds of silence before ending the recording and moving to the next priority.

You can see the full parameters for Record() function here: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Application_Record

Answer (score 0):

You should read and possible change dsp.conf for "silence" margin.

```
; Length of sound (in milliseconds) before a period of silence is considered
; to be a change from talking to silence or a period of noise converts silence
; to talking.  [default=256]
;
silencethreshold=256
```